# Add class to Add to Cart Woocommerce button text on single product page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a class only on the add to cart button **text** for design purpose.

I tried but it doesn't work :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'add_custom_class_to_add_to_cart_button_text' );
function add_custom_class_to_add_to_cart_button_text() {
    $text = ('<span class="custom-class">' . __( 'Add to Cart Button Text', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>') ;
    return $text;
}
```

Do you know how to target ATC button text only or wrap the text ?

Comment: How is it working? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works on single product page :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'add_custom_class_to_add_to_cart_button_text' );
function add_custom_class_to_add_to_cart_button_text( $text ) {
    echo '<span class="atc-text">' . $text . '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' , 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text' ); 
function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text() {
global $product;

$product_type = $product->product_type;

switch ( $product_type ) {
    case 'external':
        return __( 'Take me to their site!', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'grouped':
        return __( 'VIEW THE GOOD STUFF', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'simple':
        return __( 'WANT. NEED. ADD!', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    case 'variable':
        return __( 'Select the variations, yo!', 'woocommerce' );
    break;
    default:
        return __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

}